# How to handle service-calls in a portlet-environment (2 requests per action)

Tags: jsf-2, portlet, postconstruct

I am looking for alternatives to a session-flag when using a portlet (jsr-286) together with JSF 2.0.

The problem is that I have to use @PostConstruct to load data from the backend. The reason is because the portlet is loaded within a dynamic portlet-page at runtime. So when the portlet is loaded the first time, RESTORE_VIEW is called for the RenderRequest and several Webservices are called to load some data.

When triggering an action on the page I run into the problem with the two requests in a portlet-runtime: first the ActionRequest is handled, again RESTORE_VIEW is called, and the LifeCycle continues till the end of INVOKE_APPLICATION.
Now, the RenderRequest is processed which calls RESTORE_VIEW and RENDER_RESPONSE.

My BackingBeans are all @RequestScoped and this means that @PostContruct is called twice when invoking an action, and this causes an performance issue because the webservices are also called twice.
The simplest idea now was to use a session-flag within the portlet that is used to control when backend-services need to be called and when not.

Are there better alternatives to this approach? How do other people handle Bean-Initialization in a Portlet-JSF2-Environment?